# pyside QTableWidgetItem.text() bug?

Tags: python-3.x, pyside

I've been struggling with a persistent problem, and i believe it's a bug from PySide, but I'm not sure.
I'm developing a client chat which simply retrieves a list of available rooms, when the user clicks on an item, the room name is taken from the list and it's used to enter in the room.

The main problem is that i can't find a way to get some of the room names, many rooms uses utf-8 encoding characters. Displaying them is okay, they are displayed correctly, however when i want to get their value, a ValueError is thrown and I'm unable to get this from my QTableWidget.

I believe it would be okay to live with this bug if it didn't murder my program after some time with a segfault. I've lost 4 hours of testing to find out that `QTableWidgetItem.text()` is the guilty function. I already tried using `QTableWidgetItem.data(0)`, and it appears to give an unpredictable behavior over the time, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

I got this code from somewhere on internet and modified a bit to show how it (does not) works.

```
import sys

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


title = ["one", "two", "three"]

# i dont have control over the content in my problem, but here is one example:
data = [[" ", "a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["f", "g", "h"]]

class TableWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        colcnt = len(data[0])
        rowcnt = len(data)
        self.tablewidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(rowcnt, colcnt)

        # resizing stuff
        vheader = QtGui.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical)
        vheader.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.tablewidget.setVerticalHeader(vheader)
        hheader = QtGui.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        hheader.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.tablewidget.setHorizontalHeader(hheader)
        self.tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(title)

        # put the values inside the QTableWidget
        for i in range(rowcnt):
            for j in range(colcnt):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data[i][j])  # it works and shows stuff properly
                print(item.text())  # if you comment this, the code works
                self.tablewidget.setItem(i, j, item)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tablewidget)
        self.setLayout(layout)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = TableWindow()
    widget.show()
    widget.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It certainly looks like a bug, and it still exists in the latest version (PySide-1.2.4). The same code works fine in PyQt4.

Comment: it looks like PySide can't handle emoji in strings at all, my program was being killed because a signal was emitting a string with emoji in it, i fixed this by using the type `bytes` instead of `str` on the emition. I used a list of names to store each index from the QTableWidget, and then i simply get the items from this list instead of trying to read it from the QTableWidgetItem, it works pretty well, unfortunately i use QLineEdit.text() to retrieve the name of the selected room, and its also bugged, i know how to make all the workaround for these bugs, i just wished i didn't need them

Comment: well then you could open a PR, or raise an issue...i don't know how active pyside is nowadays